# Large amount of smoke is coming out from exhaust, what could it be?

Tags: ford, oil-leak, smoke, fusion

We have a 2015 Ford Fusion Titanium. As driving out of the complex we noticed a large amount of white smoke coming from the back of the car along with a lot of noise coming from the front of the car. In the morning we saw oil leaking from under the car. Now we took it to an auto shop that is quoting us $1500 for repairs ... I don't trust them because this is the third time we have gone to their shop with in the last 3 weeks and it's always something more expensive that needs to be fixed, what could this be?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! White smoke from the exhaust is usually burnt antifreeze. All I can tell you is with white smoke, leaking oil, and noises up front, if they are quoting you $1500 for repairs, it sounds as though you're getting off cheap. That engine is in a might bit of trouble.

Comment: So what were they quoting needed to be replaced these last 3 weeks? Have you gotten a second opinion from another shop? If you're actively leaking oil your engine is probably toast at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Head gaskets, I'd say.

Are you the original owners? If so, take it straight to the dealer. The car has a 3-year/36,000 standard warranty, and a 5 year/60,000 powertrain warranty.

If you purchased second hand, contact the dealer anyway - but I'm not sure which/how much of the warranty can be transferred.

Failing that, at least take it to two other garages for quotes. White smoke is rarely good unless you''re electing a Pope...

Answer (score 0):

Motor might need work. Your motor might just be going out. I had a small Geo, white smoke coming out when started up. One day it just cut off and would not start. Took it in and motor was dead. Plus head gaskets can cause this too I've seen. White smoke says problem.